# JS how to group hh:mm - hours arrays without minutes

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

How can we group hour arrays according to hours.

```
var hours = ["22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22", "23:37", "23:52", "0:07", "0:22", "0:37", "0:52", "1:07", "1:22", "1:37", "1:52", "2:07", "2:22", "3:07", "3:22", "4:07", "4:22", "4:37", "4:52", "5:07", "5:22", "6:07", "6:22",  "7:07", "7:22", "7:37", "7:52", "8:07", "8:22", "8:37", "8:52", "9:07", "9:22", "9:37", "9:52", "10:07", "10:22", "10:37", "10:52", "11:07", "11:22", "11:37", "11:52", "12:07", "12:22", "14:07", "14:52", "15:07", "15:22", "16:07", "16:22", "16:37", "16:52", "17:07",  "17:52", "18:07", "18:22", "18:37", "18:52", "19:07", "19:22", "19:37", "19:52", "20:07", "20:22", "20:37", "20:52", "21:07", "21:22", "21:37", "21:52", "22:07", "22:22", "22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22"]
```

As you see, an hour has multiple minute, like `22:37, 22:52`. 
I want to create new array like

```
22: ["22:37", "22:52"],
23: [ "23:07", "23:22", "23:37", "23:52"],
0 : ["0:07", "0:22", "0:37", "0:52"], // next day
... 
20: ["20:07", "20:22", "20:37", "20:52"],// next day
21: ["21:07", "21:22", "21:37", "21:52"],// next day
22: ["22:22", "22:37", "22:52"],
23: ["23:07", "23:22"]
```

It contains two days hours.

I tried like this

```
var groupHours = hours.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
    v = v.split(':')[0] // getting only hours 
    if (v === a[i - 1]) {
        r[r.length - 1].push(v);
    } else {
        r.push(v === a[i + 1] ? [v] : v);
    }
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(groupHours)
```

But it gives me this result

[image]

Comment: Do you want an object as your output? Is your array always sorted?

Comment: @NickParsons as you see, it contains almos 24 hours. begins from today like 22 to tomorrow 23. It like a time schedule. As object it does not matter. it can be an array or object. Just want to re-create array with it's key will be hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var hours = ["22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22", "23:37", "23:52", "0:07", "0:22", "0:37", "0:52", "1:07", "1:22", "1:37", "1:52", "2:07", "2:22", "3:07", "3:22", "4:07", "4:22", "4:37", "4:52", "5:07", "5:22", "6:07", "6:22",  "7:07", "7:22", "7:37", "7:52", "8:07", "8:22", "8:37", "8:52", "9:07", "9:22", "9:37", "9:52", "10:07", "10:22", "10:37", "10:52", "11:07", "11:22", "11:37", "11:52", "12:07", "12:22", "14:07", "14:52", "15:07", "15:22", "16:07", "16:22", "16:37", "16:52", "17:07",  "17:52", "18:07", "18:22", "18:37", "18:52", "19:07", "19:22", "19:37", "19:52", "20:07", "20:22", "20:37", "20:52", "21:07", "21:22", "21:37", "21:52", "22:07", "22:22", "22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22"]

var h = {};

for (var hh of hours) {
    try { 
        h[hh.split(':')[0]].push(hh);    
    }
    catch (e) {
        h[hh.split(':')[0]] = [hh];
    }
}

console.log(h);
```

**Update**

Solution for several days:

```js
var hours = ["22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22", "23:37", "23:52", "0:07", "0:22", "0:37", "0:52", "1:07", "1:22", "1:37", "1:52", "2:07", "2:22", "3:07", "3:22", "4:07", "4:22", "4:37", "4:52", "5:07", "5:22", "6:07", "6:22",  "7:07", "7:22", "7:37", "7:52", "8:07", "8:22", "8:37", "8:52", "9:07", "9:22", "9:37", "9:52", "10:07", "10:22", "10:37", "10:52", "11:07", "11:22", "11:37", "11:52", "12:07", "12:22", "14:07", "14:52", "15:07", "15:22", "16:07", "16:22", "16:37", "16:52", "17:07",  "17:52", "18:07", "18:22", "18:37", "18:52", "19:07", "19:22", "19:37", "19:52", "20:07", "20:22", "20:37", "20:52", "21:07", "21:22", "21:37", "21:52", "22:07", "22:22", "22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22"]


function split_by_days(hours) {
    var s = hours.join('#');
    s.match(/[1-9]:\d+#0/g).forEach(t=>s=s.split(t).join(t.replace('#','\n')));
    return s.split('\n').map(x => x.split('#'));
}

function day_to_obj(day) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var hours of day) {
        try { obj[hours.split(':')[0]].push(hours) }
        catch (e) { obj[hours.split(':')[0]] = [hours] }
    }
    return obj;
}

var days = split_by_days(hours);

var array_of_days_objects = days.map(d => day_to_obj(d));

console.log(array_of_days_objects);
```

Comment: it is okey but it merges two days' hours. 22:37 is the hour of today, but 22:07 at the end, tomorrow hour

Comment: Show us how exactly how should the result looks like. Otherwise it's impossible to guess what else you have on your mind.

Comment: I edited re-creating array detail. It contains two days hours. The point is find the how many hours it takes. And this hours contains how many data.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just to show one more alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

- Iterating through the array, and saving each time to a key based on its prefix.
- **Days are indexed** starting from `0`, hours are nested within days.

```js
var hours = ["22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22", "23:37", "23:52", "0:07", "0:22", "0:37", "0:52", "1:07", "1:22", "1:37", "1:52", "2:07", "2:22", "3:07", "3:22", "4:07", "4:22", "4:37", "4:52", "5:07", "5:22", "6:07", "6:22", "7:07", "7:22", "7:37", "7:52", "8:07", "8:22", "8:37", "8:52", "9:07", "9:22", "9:37", "9:52", "10:07", "10:22", "10:37", "10:52", "11:07", "11:22", "11:37", "11:52", "12:07", "12:22", "14:07", "14:52", "15:07", "15:22", "16:07", "16:22", "16:37", "16:52", "17:07", "17:52", "18:07", "18:22", "18:37", "18:52", "19:07", "19:22", "19:37", "19:52", "20:07", "20:22", "20:37", "20:52", "21:07", "21:22", "21:37", "21:52", "22:07", "22:22", "22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22"];

let timeObject = {}
let currentDay = 0
let lastHour = 0

for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
  let time = hours[i]
  let hour = time.split(":")[0]
  currentDay = parseInt(hour) >= lastHour ? currentDay : currentDay + 1

  if (!timeObject[currentDay]) {
    timeObject[currentDay] = {}
  }

  if (!timeObject[currentDay][hour]) {
    timeObject[currentDay][hour] = []
  }

  timeObject[currentDay][hour].push(time)

  lastHour = parseInt(hour)
}

console.log(timeObject)
```

Comment: dude but I am confused when I used in code schema, https://i.stack.imgur.com/qogzj.png I took this result? It differs in 10 o'clok

Comment: @apsisxcoder What does the object look like extended?

Comment: It differs 4 days, if I use like your code. Every 10 o'clock, it increment the day. See in picture, at the top, you will see hours, and result https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DhKs.png The hours contains 150 values. It almost contains 30 hours. But it gives me 4 days

Comment: @apsisxcoder Yep, I spotted my mistake, I've made an edit to the post now. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I think the problem is in array sub indexing. Because as you saw in the image, days increments like 0 1 2 3  but 0 and 1 days results also increments like 9 10 11 12

Comment: @apsisxcoder The problem was with the way I was comparing hours to see if a new day had passed. When using a number to access an object it always refers to the key.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right just try to change the accumulator type from **array** to **object**.
try this:

```
var groupHours = hours.reduce((hrs, current) => {
    const getCurrentHour = current.split(':')[0]
    if(hrs[getCurrentHour] && hrs[getCurrentHour].length > 0) 
    hrs[getCurrentHour].push(current)
    else
    hrs[getCurrentHour] = [current]
    return hrs;
}, {});
```

Comment: Still it combines two days hours. there are two 22 hour, the first is now, the other is next day

Answer (score 0):

```
function groupHours() {
  const times = ["22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22", "23:37", "23:52", "0:07", "0:22", "0:37", "0:52", "1:07", "1:22", "1:37", "1:52", "2:07", "2:22", "3:07", "3:22", "4:07", "4:22", "4:37", "4:52", "5:07", "5:22", "6:07", "6:22",  "7:07", "7:22", "7:37", "7:52", "8:07", "8:22", "8:37", "8:52", "9:07", "9:22", "9:37", "9:52", "10:07", "10:22", "10:37", "10:52", "11:07", "11:22", "11:37", "11:52", "12:07", "12:22", "14:07", "14:52", "15:07", "15:22", "16:07", "16:22", "16:37", "16:52", "17:07",  "17:52", "18:07", "18:22", "18:37", "18:52", "19:07", "19:22", "19:37", "19:52", "20:07", "20:22", "20:37", "20:52", "21:07", "21:22", "21:37", "21:52", "22:07", "22:22", "22:37", "22:52", "23:07", "23:22"];
  let groupedHours = {};

  times.forEach((time) => {
    const [hour, minutes] = time.split(":");
    let existing = groupedHours[hour];
    if (existing) {
      groupedHours[hour] = [...existing, time];
    } else {
      groupedHours[hour] = [time];
    }
  });

  return groupedHours;
}

console.log(groupHours());
```

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried this and the output looks rather wrong.

Comment: Updated. Try again @YuriKhristich

Comment: Now it gets me this: https://i.imgur.com/LFcmgAv.png which is doesn't look well too. Please don't feel obligated to fix this. It's just a  matter of idle curiosity, actually.